# adust jq to match multiple nested levels on left and right side of select()

Tags: jq

UPDATE 2: using @pmf updated answer, the use of arbitrary deep recursion `..` does work, even if the json becomes more complex. see `https://jqplay.org/s/LahEV9zqfJL` and `type == "cow"` or `type == "lion",` will return a reduced or empty parent object as requested.

UPDATE 1 : based on answer from @pmf, I have updated the complexity of the json to reflect more real world. In this case the `any()` addition does return the json with only the matching value for `.car[], .boat[]` removed. however `.plane` still deletes the whole `.plane` record

```
[example][https://jqplay.org/s/bNaI6MESxAl]
```

can I modify this jq to get the following outputs

```
jq 'del(.car[], .boat[], .plane | select(any(.type == "dog")))' 
// this outputs as expected
{
  ...
   "car":{ delta{...} }
  ...
}

jq 'del(.car[], .boat[], .plane | select(any(.type == "lion")))' 
//should output
{ 
 ...
   "plane":{ delta: {} }
 ...
}
```

<s>I tried substituting `select(.[].type == "lion")` with `select(.[-1] == "lion")` thinking the `-1` whould replace `.[].type` but this does not work.</s>

So balancing the left and right side for unknown depth is the issue for me. ie: making left  `... .plane[]) |  select(.type == "lion")?)` works but stops  `... .car[] ... | select(.type == "dog")?)` from working.

Is it possible to use a single statement to balance the depth on both sides when nesting depth is unknown? ie `car > type = 3 levels`, `plane > type = 2 levels`

```
    {
  "www":"hello",  
  "car": {
    "alpha": {
      "in": {
        "model": "alpha",
        "dir": "in",
        "type": "dog"
      },
      "out": {
        "model": "alpha",
        "dir": "out",
        "type": "dog"
      }
    },
    "delta": {
      "in": {
        "model": "delta",
        "dir": "in",
        "type": "bird"
      },
      "out": {
        "model": "delta",
        "dir": "out",
        "type": "bird"
      }
    }
    
  },
  "boat":{
    "beta": {
      "in": {
        "model": "beta",
        "dir": "in",
        "type": "mouse"
      }
    }
  },
  "plane":{
      "beta": {
        "model": "beta",
        "dir": "in",
        "type": "lion"
      },
      "delta": {
        "model": "delta",
        "dir": "in",
        "type": "bee"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: see `//should output`  in first section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `select(.[].type == …)` will split up into multiple comparisons, and thus yield multiple results, and perform multiple deletions. It looks like you want to use `any` which returns `true` (once) if at least one item matches. Specifically in this case, you can make use of `any(…)` (providing only the condition) which is a shortcut to `any(.[]; …)` (where the generator is preset to `.[]`):

```bash
del(.car[], .boat[], .plane | select(any(.type == "dog")))
```

As for the disappearing `.plane`: You are using `del`, which when applied to a field inside an object (as it is the case with `.car[]` or `.boat[]`), the field is deleted but the parent object stays there (in this case it remains empty, and shows as `{}`). But with `del` applied to `.plane`, it will delete exactly that: the whole `.plane` object. If you want to retain it as an empty object, it is a different logic wrt the other deletions, which needs to be added to your filter.

One way would be to change `.plane` into `.plane[]` (so that only its fields will be deleted), and then compensate for that shift by adding `.` to the list of generators (returning to the two-argument version). You could also change it to `..` for arbitrary deep recursion:

```bash
del(.car[], .boat[], .plane[] | select(any(., .[]; .type == "lion")?))
# or
del(.car[], .boat[], .plane[] | select(any(..; .type == "lion")?))
```

Another way, if you want to keep the `.car[], .boat[], .plane` list untouched, could be to add a minimal set of empty objects to the deletion result, acting as some sort of default content:

```bash
{plane: {}} + del(.car[], .boat[], .plane | select(any(.type == "lion")))
```